# R cooccur package error when plotting data

Tags: r, plot

I'm having trouble with the cooccur package. After creating the cooccur object, I'm trying to plot it to obtain a heatmap of positive/negative co-occurrence. This should be simple- the code in the example is just "plot(*cooccur_object*)" but it's throwing an error: **Error in zero_range(from) : x must be length 1 or 2**. I've included reproducible code, and any ideas are welcome. The error seems to depend on the numbers themselves, as the example code works perfectly with the "finches" data set and only throws errors occasionally when the numbers are randomly generated. The reproducible code below throws the error, but if you change the seed it'll sometimes run and sometimes won't. Any thoughts?

```
set.seed(13532)
a <- rnorm(100)
a[a>0] <- 1
a[a<0] <- 0
a
b <- matrix(a, ncol = 10)
df <- as.data.frame(b)
names(df) <- c(paste("Subject", 1:10))
row.names(df) <- c(paste("Disease", LETTERS[1:10]))
df

library(cooccur)
cooc <- cooccur(df)
plot(cooc)
summary(cooc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your interest in cooccur. I am the package author and am willing to communicate with you about issues you have.

Since you have created a random matrix, the results of the co-occurrence analysis are (unsurprisingly) that there are zero significant results... everything is random. Unfortunately, I did not think about adding a warning that there were no results to plot, and I thank you for bringing this to my attention!

Feel free to email me, I don't always keep up with the forums.

Best,
Dan Griffith

Comment: Good to know! I'd created the random matrix as a reproducible result, when I'm actually working with a data set that I'd rather not post on the internet. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Great! Let me know by email if you would like me to look at that specific analysis.